# SGD optimization in Keras does not move perpendicular to level curves?

Tags: python, keras, gradient-descent

I'm performing linear regression using Keras. My dataset is comprised of 50 1D input points and 50 1D output points. In order to perform linear regression, I'm training a neural network with a single layer and a single neuron, with no activation function. The neural network is defined as

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='zeros', 
bias_initializer='zeros'))
```

and I ask Keras to find the optimal value of w and b, using SGD as the optimizer and the mean squared error as the loss function.

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01))
model.fit(x,y,epochs=100, callbacks=[history], verbose=0, batch_size=50);
```

where `history` is a callback I created to save the current weight and bias at each step of the optimization.

I then proceed to plot the level curves of the loss function, together with the optimization trajectory in the `w` x `b` space. The output is the following.

[image: gradient descent trajectory]

The optimization trajectory is shown in red circles, and the global optimum is shown as a blue 'x'. This seems reasonable, since we started at `[0,0]` and after each iteration we approach the global optimum. Eventually the gradient starts to get so small that we stop improving.

**However**, I understand that by using gradient descent, one would always move in the direction of the gradient at the current point (i.e. perpendicular to the level curves). This optimization trajectory doesn't seem to behave like that. Is Keras `SGD` optimizer doing something else under the hood? Or am I missing something?

EDIT:
Although the plot seems to illustrate that the level curves are parallel lines, they are actually ellipsoids, but very elongated. Choosing a different range to plot them reveals this.

EDIT 2:
To avoid any confusion related to how I could have plotted the image shown in this question, I have now created a [gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/JulianoLagana/59a33374b160c39f27586fdbf1cb2cd0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* orthogonal (0.2 vs -5 slopes), but the x/y units of your graph aren't the same. Scaling in a given direction doesn't preserve orthogonality.

Comment: You are completely correct. Sometimes it's easy to miss the simplest things. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind, that you are using a `SGD` which is a `Stochastic Gradient Descent`. A visualization of the difference in the trajectories one gets by using `SGD` compared to vanilla `GD` can be seen in the following image:
[image] ([source](https://wikidocs.net/3413))

You can see, that the `SGD` trajectory is not perpendicular to the level lines, but moves differently. Maybe this is already explaining the form of your trajectory.

Comment: This was my first thought. However, please note that I'm using a batch size which is equal to the size of my training dataset:
`model.fit(x,y,epochs=100, callbacks=[history], verbose=0, batch_size=50);`
Hence, I'm using gradient descent, not stochastic gradient descent, correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should realize that as you are not using activation functions, your neural network is only able to represent linear systems (equivalent to a matrix multiplication). The non linear activation functions are bringing the representativity capacity of a neural network.

You are actually not performing a linear regression. If you want to do so, with for example a degree 2 polynomial, you should add the squared parameters as an input. Scikit-learn provides this transformation thanks to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html

Let's assume you have a function of two inputs x and y, performing a linear regression as you did would be having an input layer with `x, x^2, xy, y, y^2` and one output neuron.

Edits:
However, in the (w,b) space, you should actually be able to reach the global minimum. However, there are no results about the speed of convergence. If you look at your loss function, you can notice that it is stretched a lot in one direction: it is equivalent to say that the Hessian matrix has two eigenvalues with very different magnitudes. It means that you will be able to learn quickly in one direction (the one of the biggest eingenvalues), but slowly in the other direction.

In neural networks optimization, it is out of questions to compute the Hessian matrix, as it would require to many computation at each steps. However, some learning alogrithm are able to escape saddle points and badly condition (like yours) optimization problems. SGD performs in general poorly and it is barely used anymore. Have a look at http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/, knowing all these optimizers are included in Keras. For you I would first try to add momentum to increase the speed of convergence, as you say it can actually converge if you wait long enough.

Comment: I understand that by only having `x` as my input, and no activation functions, my neural network can only learn linear relationships. This is what I intended, since I'm doing linear regression (i.e. y = w*x + b, find w and b). However, this does not restrict the optimization trajectory to be a line. In fact, it is not. If I run the optimization for long enough, the trajectory slowly converges to the global optimum.

Comment: Thansk for your time, Nathan. However, if I understood you correctly, this answer fails to address my main question: why aren't the gradient descent steps orthogonal to the level curves in the figure I plotted?

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me if you already took that into consideration, I can't see how you created your graph.

The gradients depends on the input data.

A neuron has the formula `w.x + b`, where x is the input.

.

The gradient in function of w and b is: (x , 1).

So, it varies depending on the inputs.

But don't forget also that the gradients are also affected by the loss function, which in your case squares the differences.

In order to see the level curves, you'd have to apply a chain rule.

```
Loss = [(wx + b) - y]^2
```

So you're gradients are:

```
W: 2.[(wx + b) - y].x
B: 2.[(wx + b) - y].1
```

Comment: I did, actually. The loss at each (`w`, `b`) point is computed using the current values of `w` and `b` at that point, and all the training set inputs and outputs.

Comment: Have you considered the squares in your loss function? Maybe you could try 'mae' instead of 'mse'.

Comment: I fail to see how that's relevant... could you elaborate more? Perhaps the fact that the level curves seem parallel lines is making you infer that I'm plotting a linear loss function? However, that's simply an artifact of my choice of range in each axis. The level curves are actually ellipsoids, but very elongated ones. If I plot them using a different range, it's possible to see it.